# Android Remember previous login account

Tags: android

I am developing an android application. To use my app you must have an id, so I choose to use AccountManager.
[Android Develope](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

From this manager I can retrieve an account (google, twitter or whatever).

This works ok, but I don't know what is the best way to store this account choice so that it doesn't ask to choose an account everytime the app is launched.

Do I create a file and store the choice in it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about SharedPreferences. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for saving a key-value pair that persists even if the application gets killed. Then you can save the last logged account.